# Most efficient way to find all pairs from given integers that sum up to target value with specific conditions

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for an efficient way to print pairs from a large volume of integers that sum up to a target value under certain conditions:

- first int should be smaller than the second int the pair
- the printing should be ascending by the first in in the pair

I've made up some spaghetti code that seems to be more efficient in time complexity than two loops, however, it doesn't include the sorting. I've currently run out of ideas.

My questions are the following:

1. What would be the best way to get the output sorted?
2. Is there any other way to improve the time complexity than my current solution?

The output may be large, so I'm wondering if I should replace the `System.out.println()`.

I have to print out all the pairs. One int can be in many pairs. The input can grow up to few hundred thousand of integers.

Given target 12:
Example Input:
2 10 0 8 4 12 8

Example Output:
0 12
2 10
4 8
4 8

```
public static void myFindPair(int[] arr, int target) {

    // Key = difference, value = index
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int difference = target - arr[i];
        map.put(difference, i);
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (map.containsKey(arr[i]) && map.get(arr[i]) != i) {
            int first = arr[i];
            int second = arr[map.get(arr[i])];
            if (first < second) {
                System.out.println(first + " " + second);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you required to find all such pairs or just one?

Comment: Add some example inputs and outputs.

Comment: If the first int is smaller than the second int, the two values are by definition in ascending order, so aren't the 2 bullets just saying the same thing?

Comment: Please share more details. Is there anything not working with your code?

Comment: I have edited the post and added example input and output.

Comment: ***Please do mention the constraints of the problem.*** *What is the maximum length of the array? What is the maximum size of the elements of the array?* If the constraints are not too big, your question can be solved in `O(n)`. If they are big enough, `O(n*log n)` is the best solution I am aware of.

Comment: @AKSingh The input can be even a few hundreds of thousands.

Comment: *Your sample output is wrong.* Input: `2 10 0 8 4 12 8`, only one `4` is present. However, in output: `0 12 2 10 4 8 4 8`, two `4` are present.

Comment: @AKSingh: The sample output contributes to *specifying* the required output. The 4 is in (8, 4) and (4, 8), both printed smaller first as per first bullet point.

Comment: The output isn't fully specified: What about more than one occurrence of target/2? How many pairs `4 8` need to be printed when there are, say, 3 `8`s and 2 `4`s?

Answer (score 5):

Start by sorting the array. If `arr` is sorted and `arr[0] + arr[arr.length - 1] > target`, then `arr[arr.length - 1]` can't possibly be in a pair; you added it to the smallest possible value and it was still too big for the target. Similarly if `arr[0] + arr[arr.length] < target`, then `arr[0]` can't possibly be part of a pair. This leads to the following algorithm.

```
public /* return type */ findPair(int[] arr, int target)
{
  Arrays.sort(arr);

  int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1;
  
  while (i < j) {
    int sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
    if (sum < target) i++;
    else if (sum > target) j--;
    else {
      /* sum == target, so add arr[i] and arr[j] to a set of solutions. */
      /* I'm assuming that the elements of arr are unique. */
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }

  return /* set of solutions */
}
```

Comment: This section is for answers. This is not an answer but a hint towards an answer and thus should be a comment on the question.

Comment: Thank you, @JeffC. I'm getting used to the way everyone does things around here. Is it bad to give the answer? This feels like a homework question.

Comment: I feel the same way. I think that's up to you to decide. When I see things like this, I tend to do what you did but put it into a comment so that I can hopefully lead the person to find the right answer rather than giving them the answer straight away. But... I can pretty much guarantee you others will just answer before OP has had a chance to consider your guidance and come up with their own answer.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I really enjoy your solution. However in my case, the elements of the array are not unique, I will try to tune your solution to my needs. However, I have avoided the sorting bit in my attempts to solve it to keep the time complexity of the whole task as low as possible. (but not sure it's a good idea).

Comment: If the elements aren't unique but the array is sorted, you can just advance the points while the next elements are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Here is *one possible solution* to your problem:

---

### *Using Counting Sort*

> *Let length on input array A* = `n`
>
> *Let range of input, that is, maximum element of the array* =  `k`

**Algorithm:**

```
Store the frequency of each element of the array A.
Use the frequency array to find pairs.
```

**Example:**

```
A = 2 10 0 8 4 12 8 4
```

Here is the corresponding frequency array:

```
element:     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
frequency:   1  0  1  0  2  0  0  0  2  0  1   0   1
```

Using the frequency array, we can easily find pairs *in ascending order* which have a *target sum* of say `T`.

We know, if `a` and `b` are elements of array `A` where `a` <= `b` and they make a pair then,

```
a + b = T
b = T - a
```

*Using this, we can check if frequency of `a` > `0`  and frequency of `b` > `0`, then such a pair is possible. Doing this we can find all the pairs in `O(k)` where `k` = **range of input***.

**Solution code:**

```
private static void printPair(int[] A, int targetSum)
{
    //find the maximum element
    int max = A[0];

    for (int element: A) max = Math.max(max, element);    

    //Make a frequency array
    int[] frequency = new int[max+1];
    for (int element: A) frequency[element]++;

    //Find pairs
    for (int i = 0;i < frequency.length/2;i++)
    {
        if (targetSum - i < 0) break;

        if (frequency[i] > 0 && frequency[targetSum-i] > 0)
        {
            while (Math.min(frequency[i], frequency[targetSum-i]) > 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Pair: " + i + "\t" + (targetSum - i));
                System.out.println();

                frequency[i]--;
                frequency[targetSum - i]--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*There is a while loop also present inside, since if a single pair is present in the array `f` times, we need to print it `f` times*.

*The solution I posted can be improved if you use better implementation of `counting sort`.* In my solution I used:

> *Range of input, that is, maximum element of the array* =  `k`

I did this purposely so the solution is simpler to understand. However, ***the solution will be more efficient if we change range to:***

> *New range of input, that is, maximum element of the array - minimum element of the array* =  `k`

***Making this change would also make this solution to work negative numbers.***

*If you are using this range, you will need to make some changes in the solution* which are not that tough to make if you can understand the solution I provided. *You will only need to change how you access the frequency of each element of the array.* Here is a link to the improved counting sort: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

**Time complexity of the solution:**

The solution has a time complexity of `O(n+k)`. *This might seem like a *linear time complexity*. However, it depends on the input.*

Suppose:

```
A = 4 3 30 5 1
```

Here,

```
n = 5 
k = 30
```

`k` is almost equal to `n^2`. Hence, time complexity of the solution becomes `O(n + n^2)` = `O(n^2)`. *So the time complexity strictly depends on the type of inputs possible.*

---

*I hope I have helped you. I have not gone in detail about the solution code since doing so would have made the answer too long. However, do comment if you are having trouble understanding the explanation, solution code or you also want me to post second possible solution. I would be happy to help you.*

Comment: Note that your interpretation of the task/problem gives the `Example Output` for a *modified input*.

Comment: (That is one complicated way to determine "the multiplicity of a pair". How about `for (int m = Math.min(frequency[i], frequency[targetSum-i]) ; 0 <= --m ; ) System.out.println(i + "\t" + (targetSum - i));`.) (I think it should be the product of frequencies rather than the minimum.)

Answer (score 0):

**You can make a loop like this**

```
function twoSum($nums, $target)

{

$filterdArray = [];
$indexes = [];

foreach ($nums as $key => $val) {
    if ($val <= $target) {
        $x =  $target - $val;
        if (array_key_exists($x, $filterdArray)) {
            $indexes[] = $key; //0
            $indesxes[] = $filterdArray[$x]; //0
            return $indexes;
        }

        $filterdArray[] = [$val => $key]; //[3=>0]
    }
}
}
```